# STM32F7 CubeMX FreeRTOS and USB CDC

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-device, freertos, stm32f7

I'm using FreeRTOS generated with the help of CubeMX. Everything was working fine until I added USB CDC unit. When I used CDC_Transmit_FS() before starting kernel, I could receive data over USB. However, when I paste the same code to thread, this is not working.

Comment: Add code please and check if this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597612/stm32-usb-vcp-virtual-com-port) has any relevance in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There are two defines in the file usbd_cdc_if.c:

```
#define APP_RX_DATA_SIZE  4
#define APP_TX_DATA_SIZE  4
```

The value 4 should be changed to 64. After that everything works great.